# bytes.decode() in Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, decode, python-2.x

In the source code of [sqlalchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_3/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py#L2212) I see following

```
    val = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    if util.py3k and isinstance(val, bytes):
        val = val.decode()
```

Why we do decode only for Python3 and doesn't do it for Python2?

Comment: At first glance, `val` is immediately pass to a function that assumes a `str` value. The same code in Python 2, being more lax about the difference between `str` and `unicode`, may not care which `val` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Python 3*, "normal" strings are *Unicode* (as opposed to *Python 2* where they are (*Extended*) *ASCII* (or *ANSI*)). According to [[Python 3.Docs]: Unicode HOWTO - The String Type](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type):

> Since Python 3.0, the language’s [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) type contains Unicode characters, meaning any string created using `"unicode rocks!"`, `'unicode rocks!'`, or the triple-quoted string syntax is stored as Unicode.

Example:

- *Python **3***:

  > ```py
  > >>> import sys
  > >>> sys.version
  > '3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>>
  > >>> b = b"abcd"
  > >>> s = "abcd"
  > >>> u = u"abcd"
  > >>>
  > >>> type(b), type(s), type(u)
  > (<class 'bytes'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>)
  > >>>
  > >>> b.decode()
  > 'abcd'
  > >>> s.decode()
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  > AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
  > >>> u.decode()
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  > AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
  > ```
- *Python **2***:

  > ```py
  > >>> import sys
  > >>> sys.version
  > '2.7.10 (default, Mar  8 2016, 15:02:46) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)]'
  > >>>
  > >>> b = b"abcd"
  > >>> s = "abcd"
  > >>> u = u"abcd"
  > >>>
  > >>> type(b), type(s), type(u)
  > (<type 'str'>, <type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>)
  > >>>
  > >>> b.decode()
  > u'abcd'
  > >>> s.decode()
  > u'abcd'
  > >>> u.decode()
  > u'abcd'
  > ```

*val* will be further passed (to *_parse_server_version*) as a *str*. Since in *Python 3*, *bytes* and *str* differ, the conversion is performed.

You could also check [[SO]: Passing utf-16 string to a Windows function (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59521873/4788546).

Comment: One of the nicest comparisons I have come across...great code samples!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out a detail [documentation of string encoding frustration here](https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html).

In short, since SQLAlchemy contains legacy API that parses the data into bytes data, the said statement is a simple way to migrate the string bytes data to Unicode in python 3.